# silverlight scrollviewer Style

Tags: silverlight, blend

I want to style my scroll viewer so that it looks like this

!

Any help..? I have seen lots of example but nothing worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kunal.. I have got the solution

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/11/customized-scrolling-in-silverlight.html